# Git integration broken in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio Team Services Git for our team project. I've got VS Git Extensions (latest version) and Git for Windows installed and in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and below, Visual Studio could create pull requests within the IDE.

Now I've updated to Update 3 and I can't seem to create PRs (Pull Requests) inside the IDE. When I click New Pull Request, a browser window opens.

I've uninstalled Visual Studio's Git extensions, reinstalled it, reinstalled Git for Windows, obviously restarted etc. but no avail.

How do I get full IDE Git integration back?

Comment: Are you certain that the features have not changed in version 3?

Comment: Pull requests for GitHub, or pull requests for TFS or VS Team Services?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I haven't checked the full changelog, though I didn't find anything related to it over the web, and why on Earth should they a useful feature in an update.

Comment: @EdwardThomson PR for git using VS Team Services.

Comment: I've just tried this on 2015.3 on VSTS - I get a new browser window open, but it has a diff between my branch and master to create the PR. How are you trying to create the PR? I published the local branch, then right clicked and chose Create Pull Request in the "Branches" panel.

Comment: There were some bug fixes for Team Explorer in Update 3. e.g. 'When creating a pull request from the Team Explorer branches page context menu uses the current branch instead of the selected branch'. Have you checked the [release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) to see if any of the changes clash with how you're working?

Comment: @DaveShaw yes. both right-clicking and clicking Create Pull Request and going to Pull Requests tab and clicking New Pull Request tab yields in a browser being opened instead of in-IDE pull request creation dialog.

Comment: @Tone I've checked the release notes, there doesn't seem to be any related issue

Comment: Just as a "me too" two members on my dev team upgraded to Update 3 and are having this same issue.  The rest of us are on Update 2 and are not having problems.  We can push the branch from inside Studio and we make the pull request from a browser as a workaround.

Comment: @ShaneH I am still in the same position, could you please update me if you ever solve this?

Comment: Pull Request works for me when I'm using a GitHub repository, it just pops open a browser though.  I upgraded my studio this morning and it's not working for me, my TFS server is still 2013 and I fired up fiddler to see the  requests, and I see several 404's going to /api/v3/repos/_git/<myrepo>.

Comment: @ShaneH that is exactly my problem: Pull requests pop up in a browser. Before the update, I could open them in IDE. that is the whole purpose of my question.

Comment: +1 this functionality change in Update 3 is annoying.  The previous method described in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/pull-requests#finish is a much better workflow.

Comment: To provide some context: The VS IDE does not properly target a branch when creating PRs inside VS. On top of that, when you manually select the correct target branch, the IDE does not change the comments, forcing you to manually update them for every PR. None of these issues are present in VSO/Web Access.

Comment: Git (in VS2015) seems to be horribly broken here to! F.e. it added a compiled library that should not (happens or it might was broken as well). When I remove it, it does not show me to check in deleted file - instead no more changes are recognized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported the issue through send feedback in Visual Studio and got an email response from the TFS program manager.

This was an intentional change as there were "inconsistent behaviors and reporting issues" and they are now working on updating the release notes.

They're still working on the PR experience in VS so this could well change again in future updates.  Fingers crossed!

Comment: breaking something that was perfectly working. well definitely a move from microsoft. anyway, thank you for spending your time contacting them for details. I guess all we can do is to wait now.

Comment: Breaking things that worked fine seems to be the new MS - adding new features on products that break them beyond usability makes the new feature unusable also. That is how they killed Windows Phone, lets pray they don't kill VS the same way now.